# Регулярное выражение - Удалить всё, что ЗА двумя символами

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Подскажите есть ли, возможность выделить все символы, которые находятся вне двух символов

Думаю понятно написал, но если нет, вот пример:

> **Привет мир -** {это} **регулярное выражение!**

То, что жирным удалить соответственно и оставить только то, что между **{ }**

Comment: На каком языке программирования вы пишете? [Добавьте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1437143/edit) метку языка программирования.

Comment: Языка программирования нет, просто вопрос только про регулярное выражение, в целом такое возможно и если да, то как по общепринятым стандартам, независимо от языка это сделать?

Comment: В заголовке написано "выделить все, что за двумя символами", а в тексте вопроса "то, что жирным — удалить". Определитесь, что "оставить", что "удалить", а что "выделить". И [отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1437143/edit) ваш вопрос, чтобы было понятно.

Comment: В разных языках есть разные функции, которые работают с регулярками. В зависимости от задачи, можно *искать* по регулярке, *сравнивать* c регуляркой, *удалять* по регулярке, *заменять* текст по регулярке. Из вопроса не ясно, с какой задачей или проблемой вы столкнулись?

Comment: Поправил, ну я хотел просто удалить, часть текста за { } в обычном Sublime Text редакторе, если это не возможно в нём, как это сделать в более мощном редакторе например WebStorm.
Задача в данном случае, простая работа с текстом

Comment: Если думаете, что есть какие-то "стандартные регулярки", то вот вам [список из ~50 разных движков регулярных выражений](https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6c933f4a7d713ef712145c5eb94a1816), каждый из которых может работать по-своему.

Comment: @Vadik, 90% необходимого покрывается вполне стандартным PCRE-совместимым синтаксисом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заменить вот это на пустоту:

```
^.*?\{|\}.*$
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое работает!

Answer (score 1):

Помимо варианта от @Qwertiy, такую замену можно сделать с помощью back reference (эта фича есть не во всех реализациях регулярок, но в редакторе Sublime она должна быть).

В текстовом редакторе замените:

```
^.*?{(.*)}.*?$
```

На это:

```
$1
```

[Пример работы](https://regex101.com/r/QraCFT/1)

**Замечание**: в разных движках регулярки [могут работать по-разному](https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6c933f4a7d713ef712145c5eb94a1816) . Где-то могут поддерживаться одни фичи, где-то другие. Например, в некоторых языках или средах вместо `$1` нужно писать `\1`.

Comment: И у вас работает! Жаль не могу и вам Решение поставить, к сожалению @Qwertiy был первым(
Но спасибо вам огромное, буду юзать оба варианта, по мере необходимости!

Comment: В некоторых языках/средах вместо `$1` может быть `\1`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, спасибо, добавил это в ответ.